# Delete confirmation in php using sweetalert

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, sweetalert

I am trying to use the Sweetalert to confirm deleting data in php file, but it does not work. When I press the delete button, the sweetalert pops up without any deletion. if I dont use the sweetalert, the data will delete without any problem. Should I use ajax here? even I tried but I couldn't manage to get it working. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

html file (delete_details_top.html)

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert.min.css">

    <body>

    <form action="delete_details" method="POST"> delete_details_bottom.html

    <button class="btn btn-danger" name="delete" type="submit" onclick="deleteFunction()">Delete</button>
```

html file (delete_details_bottom.html)

```
</form>
<script>
function deleteFunction() {
event.preventDefault(); 
var form = event.target.form;
swal({
  title: "Are you sure?",
  text: "But you will still be able to retrieve this file.",
  type: "warning",
  showCancelButton: true,
  confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
  confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it!",
  cancelButtonText: "No, cancel please!",
  closeOnConfirm: false,
  closeOnCancel: false
},
function(isConfirm){
  if (isConfirm) {
    form.submit();
  } else {
    swal("Cancelled", "Your imaginary file is safe :)", "error");
  }
});
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

php file (delete_details.php)

```
<?php

    namespace Page_management;

    use classes\pdo\Database;

    $db = new Database();
    $this->formData = $_POST;
    $article = $db->sql_select("SELECT * FROM article WHERE article_no=".$_GET["article_no"]);

    $this->content .=file_get_contents("templates/delete_details_top.html");                    
    $this->content .="<input type='hidden' name='article_no' value='".$article[0]["article_no"]."' />";         
    $this->content .=file_get_contents("templates/delete_details_bottom.html");

    if(isset($_POST["delete"]))
    {
    $this->content .= $db->sql_delete("DELETE FROM article WHERE article_no= ".$_POST["article_no"]);
    $this->content .= "<div style='color:red;'>Data has been deleted!</div>";
    }       

    ?>
```

Comment: What is this line supposed to do: `$this->content .="<input type='hidden' name='article_no' value='".$article[0]["article_no"]."' />";`? If this is supposed to be php then you should put `<?php` and `?>` around it. I would also like to point out that the form doesn't have an action (`action=""`) so when you use `form.submit();`, that won't do anything because you didn't specify the file in which the data should be posted to.

Comment: And also keep in mind that you can't use php in a `.html` file so this line: `$this->content .="<input type='hidden' name='article_no' value='".$article[0]["article_no"]."' />";`, wouldn't work even if you put `<?php` and `?>` around it.

Comment: you are right , I forgot to correct that line of code ($this->content .="<input type='hidden' name='article_no' value='".$article[0]["article_no"]."' />"; 
). 
I divided  the html file into three parts 
1) delete_details_top.html
2) $this->content .="<input type='hidden' name='article_no' value='".$article[0]["article_no"]."' />";         
3) delete_details_bottom.html
to avoid using php code inside html
Many thanks